# How to convert GPS data (Garmin data with altitude) to X Y Z cartesian

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, garmin, cartesian-coordinates

My High School Calculus III class would like to mount a gps(garmin with altitude) to a remote control drone/quadcopter and then download flight data.  Our goal is to convert gps data (garmin data) to cartesian (x y z).  Once we accomplish this then we import it into Maple (Mathematical Software) and digitally model the flight path with a vector value function.  We need help with the conversion from gps to x y z.  The second part we know works because we we turned my classroom into a 3d grid and manually captured 500 points via video camera.  We then successfully run them through Maple are created our 3d path.  Any help and/or suggestions are welcomed?  Verb

Comment: Your questin omits some key information: _exactly_ what format are you downloading data? What language do you intend to use to do the conversion? What format do you require your output in?

Comment: I believe what you are asking for is called Geodetic to Earth Centered, Earth Fixed (ECEF) coordinates.